# How to write a formula for a view in xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a form keywords with 3 text boxes, how to write the "select formula" to select only one value from the form , kindly help me out how to write a formula while creating a view and to get values from a form.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What you are asking is more Notes Dev than xPages.

Comment: Without a code sample the question is hard to answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a select formula. 
The first part picks the form you are using,

The second part will include the item in the view select if the fieldName contains a value. For example if the fieldName = "You really should spend 5 minutes looking at google before asking a question like this" and the formula was `@Contains(fieldName; "google")` it would include the document in the view.

The third part will work for exact values so if the formula was `fieldname2 = "Did you even try searching for this answer?"` the document would only be included in the selection if fieldName2 was exactly equal to "Did you even try searching for this answer?"

`SELECT ((Form = "formName")) & (@Contains(fieldName; "value")& (fieldName2 = "value2") )`

Comment: @ IsMember performs better than @ Contains on keyword (multi value) fields